# How to increase invoice id on click

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to create a program when click on print the data grid view return to normal and the Invoice ID increase by one in a text box or label.

My program: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP1m8.jpg

My database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzSB9.jpg

I have tried some code, but it did not work at all.

Here is my last attempt:

```
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max (Invoice_ID) + 1 from Student_Databse_2019_HW1", con);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(dr.HasRows)
{
    while(dr.Read())
    {
        textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString();

        if(textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "1";
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

This is my error message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid object name 'Student_Databse_2019_HW1'.

Comment: Why are you using `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteScalar` ?

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim well i am a beginner that what was came to my mind

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` will return the first value in the result set, which is what you need. That'd save you a bunch of code-lines.

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim thanks i will try to learn that soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to target the table that holds the data, not the database.

In your `SqlCommand` you're doing `new SqlCommand("select max (Invoice_ID)+1 from Student_Databse_2019_HW1",con);`

Now that's translated as a query to `Select ... from table Student_Databse_2019_HW1` and since that's not the table but the actual database, it fails.

Change your query to target the table. There is never a need to target a database inside the sqlcommand because you already defined the database catalog in your `con` property.

Comment: thanks man that solved my problem now it shows the invoice number 
but when i click again it dose not increase it just stay the same 
is it because my data base ?

Comment: @MhamadAras it won't increment unless the `Invoice_ID` in your database is incremented. That's supposed to happen when you save a new invoice record.

Comment: Why do this at all? Why not use an `IDENTITY` column @MhamadAras ? This, also, could easily suffer from race conditions

Comment: @Larnu im still a beginner i do not know much about c# that what i could find by searching

Answer (score 0):

Use the actual Table name which is 'Table_Order' in sql command

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max (Invoice_ID)+1 from Table_Order",con);
```

Comment: thanks :) that fixed my problem 
but the number dose not increase when i click is it because of my database ?